# Fourth parameter on ARM SUBtract instruction

Tags: assembly, arm

Can someone explain/confirm this (particularly the SUB line) to me:

```
CMP align,#2
CMPNE align,#5
CMPNE align,#8
SUBEQ xpos,xpos,width,LSR#1
```

I was thinking it might be equivilant to the c code:

```
if ((align==2) || (align==5) || (align==8))
{
  xpos -= width >> 1;
}
```

I have found this [documentation](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0489i/CIHIBCGC.html) but I don't understand the forth parameter, `imm12`. It just says:

> The SUB instruction subtracts the value of Operand2 or imm12 from the value in Rn.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your assumption about what the code does looks correct to me.

> but I don't understand the forth parameter, imm12

The fourth parameter is not `imm12`, but rather [a shift operation](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0489i/CIHEBCBI.html) on `width` (which I assume to be an alias for one of the general purpose registers).

Comment: Thanks, yes `align`, `width` and `xpos` are all defined like so `align RN 10`. So that's a named register I understand.

Comment: Actually, the last can be a register or an immediate (hence the imm).  In the above, the immediate is 1.

Comment: You're thinking of a different immediate. The `imm12` reference in the question most likely came from the `SUB{cond} {Rd}, Rn, #imm12` form of the instruction (i.e. the OP was simply looking at the wrong form of the instruction in the documentation).